# What is the best way to restore state in MVP?

Tags: android, mvp

I have read couple of articles about restoring state in MVP. There is no clear answer but many possibilities and different ways to achieve it. Some of them recommend to retain the Presenter with Loaders  (https://medium.com/@czyrux/presenter-surviving-orientation-changes-with-loaders-6da6d86ffbbf), While others are opposing this option. They prefer to let the Presenter get destroyed and save state in cache to restore later. (https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf). So I'm kinda confused and need your advice which option to use and why?

Comment: Just like the articles this question is bound to be answered with opinion based answers - ultimately if you don't store state in your Presenter, then there is no need to keep it, if you do, then choose a solution that keeps the Presenter outside the lifecycle scope of an Activity. MVP is a design pattern .. implementation is up to you.